# Apply specified VBA excel logic to the selected row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue, I need your help with me.

I'm new in VBA excel, but I stuck with the following macro:

I want to repeat the following action, but for selected row:

Let's say the selected row in my case is : "2", its copied and paste two times down "row 3 and 4"

Then, for row 2, delete data of cells (C2 and D2)
Then for row 3, delete data of cells (B3 and D3)
Then for row 4, delete data of cells (B4 and C4)

when I applied macro for this row, I resulted the following logic:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C2:D2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B3,D3").Select
    Range("D3").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B4:C4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Any help?

To get a proper logic solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Selection.Row` property returns the currently selected row. Using this as starting point, the following code should perform the steps you need.

```
Sub test()
    Dim selectedRow As Integer
    selectedRow = Selection.Row
    
    Rows(selectedRow).Copy
    Rows(selectedRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows(selectedRow).Copy
    Rows(selectedRow + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    Range("C" & selectedRow & ":D" & selectedRow).ClearContents
    Range("B" & (selectedRow + 1) & ", D" & (selectedRow + 1)).ClearContents
    Range("B" & (selectedRow + 2) & ":C" & (selectedRow + 2)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Horrible! This work perfectly.. Can I make it to repeat for all rows?

Answer (score 3):

### Insert & Clear

```vb
Sub InsertAndClear()
    
    Dim ClearCols(): ClearCols = VBA.Array( _
        VBA.Array(3, 4), VBA.Array(2, 4), VBA.Array(2, 3))
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim MaxColumns As Long, cMax As Long, n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(ClearCols) To UBound(ClearCols)
        cMax = Application.Max(ClearCols(n))
        If cMax > MaxColumns Then
            MaxColumns = cMax
        End If
    Next n
    
    With Selection.Rows(1)
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        If cCount < MaxColumns Then Exit Sub
        .Offset(1).Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        .Copy .Offset(1).Resize(2)
        For n = LBound(ClearCols) To UBound(ClearCols)
            .Cells(n + 1, ClearCols(n)(0)).ClearContents
            .Cells(n + 1, ClearCols(n)(1)).ClearContents
        Next n
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: It was work perfectly as what I want but only after delete those two rows "If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub", could u please clarify the important of those if conditions?